# reprepro not getting package on update

Tags: reprepro

`distributions` for Ubuntu repo:

```
Origin My
Label: test-xenial
Codename: xenial
Architectures: armhf
Components: main
Description: rep to test
SignWith: 7B5AAC2D
Update: upstream-update-xenial
```

`updates`:

```
Name: upstream-update-xenial
Method: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
VerifyRelease: blindtrust
Components: main
Architectures: armhf
FilterList: purge ../mirror.packages
```

`mirror.packages` has this line:

```
libc6-dev:armhf                 install
```

command:

```
reprepro --keepunreferencedfiles --noskipold -b "$localrepo" update xenial
```

But the `libc6-dev` is not downloaded. What am I missing?

Comment: @Zanna, the server is Ubuntu 16.04 (the machine where I run `reprepro`).

Comment: Are you trying to fetch debian repository?

Comment: @Anwar, whatever.

Comment: @dadexix86, try to not to loose relevant parts when editing.

Comment: @Velkan the parts relevant to Debian are not useful, are they? I cancelled only what was about your question on Debian, before the "**EDIT:**". You did not specify that also about Ubuntu you had the same `mirror.packages` and since it was before, I assumed (wrongly, I am sorry) that it was related only to Debian.